# jquery.mask - allow users to enter separators ("." and ",")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.mask for percentage and price amounts;
I'm trying to find a way to allow users input their own "," and "." separators:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.price').mask('###.###.###,##', { reverse: true });
  $('.percent').mask('##.###,##', { reverse: false });
});
```

Here's [jsfiddle.net/muooymjd/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/muooymjd/2/)

Right now, everything's automatic; so entering an amount of 1000000, changes the value to 100.000,00 real-time and we can't use "," or "." inside of the input;

However, my intention is to allow user to input his data first (allowing him to enter 10,00, 100.00,34, 1000 or whatever he needs);

and then, only if the decimals are wrong, the input when off-focus puts "," and "." in correct places.

Is it feasible?

Comment: you should use a specific plugin like [this](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

Comment: Thank you, this made me aware I might've picked the wrong plugin to do what I need to;

I found this: https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric

which is really similiar to your example but has everything I need.